# Calculated field not updating until edited in UI

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inotifypropertychanged

I'm trying to test out data binding with XAML and C# as a novice programmer. I have two sliders that are bound to properties and I want to update a TextBox with the sum of the two values of the properties set by the sliders.

I'm using `INotifyPropertyChanged` and tried changing every property I could find but I can't get the textbox to update until I edit the textbox, at which point, the textbox updates to the correct value. Using `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` only updates the textbox as soon as I edit the textbox instead of when I select another element. I've tried writing a separate event handler that doesn't use `[CallerNameMember]` and uses a specified property but it didn't seem to change anything.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBox Grid.Row="0"
             Text="{Binding BoundNumber, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             FontSize="20"
             FontWeight="Bold"
             AllowDrop="False" />

    <Slider Grid.Row="1"
            Value="{Binding BoundNumber, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            Maximum="100"
            Minimum="10"
            IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"
            TickFrequency="10" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="2"
             Text="{Binding BoundNumber2, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             AllowDrop="False" />
    <Slider Grid.Row="3"

            Value="{Binding BoundNumber2, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            Maximum="100"
            Minimum="10"
            IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"
            TickFrequency="10" />


    <TextBox Grid.Row="4"
            Name="MathBox"
             Text="{Binding QuickMath, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}">
           </TextBox>

</Grid>
```

```
public partial class OrderScreen : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public OrderScreen()
    {
        DataContext = this;

        InitializeComponent();
     }

    private int quickMath;
    public int QuickMath
    {
        get { return _boundNumber + _boundNumber2; }
        set
        {

            if (value != quickMath)
            {
                quickMath = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();

            }
        }
    }
    private int _boundNumber;
    public int BoundNumber
    {
        get { return _boundNumber; }
        set
        {
            if (_boundNumber != value)
            {
                _boundNumber = value;
               // MathBox.Text = quickMath.ToString();
                OnPropertyChanged();

            }
        }
    }

    private int _boundNumber2;
    public int BoundNumber2
    {
        get { return _boundNumber2; }
        set
        {
            if (_boundNumber2 != value)
            {
                _boundNumber2 = value;
                MathBox.Text = quickMath.ToString();
                OnPropertyChanged();

            }
        }
    }

 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {

        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

I can get it to work with the commented out `MathBox.Text = quickMath.ToString();`   but I was hoping there was a better way to do this with data binding. Thanks in anticipation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding mechanism subscribes to the `PropertyChanged` event of `DataSource` object, so there is no need to "initialize" the event along with the `INPC` implementation, but as you might have noticed, `PropertyChanged` event for the `QuickMath` property is indeed never triggered when `BoundNumber` or `BoundNumber2` are changed.

You can fix it in different ways, e.g. explicitly call OnPropertyChanged for all affected properties:

```
private int _boundNumber;
public int BoundNumber
{
    get { return _boundNumber; }
    set
    {
        if (_boundNumber != value)
        {
            _boundNumber = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(QuickMath));
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this way you can keep `QuickMath` property a read-only. This approach works nicely in other situations, like with time-related properties, say if your data source property formats a string like *"Edited 2 minutes ago"* based on a recorded timestamp and current time and you call `PropertyChanged` as a timed task.

```
public int QuickMath => _boundNumber + _boundNumber2;
```

Alternatively, you can update `QuickMath` along with modifying `BoundNumber` and `BoundNumber2` to trigger `OnPropertyChanged()` call inside `QuickMath` setter:

```
private int _boundNumber2;
public int BoundNumber2
{
    get { return _boundNumber2; }
    set
    {
        if (_boundNumber2 != value)
        {
            _boundNumber2 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            QuickMath = BoundNumber + BoundNumber2;
        }
    }
}
```

This makes sense if the logic in `QuickMath` wouldn't allow making it a read-only property. In this case you have to adjust the getter accordingly and use private or protected setter there to avoid data inconsistency and unexpected behavior.

```
private int _quickMath;
public int QuickMath
{
    get { return _quickMath; }
    private set
    {
        if (value != _quickMath)
        {
            _quickMath = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

In both cases there is no need for two-way binding to `QuickMath`:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Text="{Binding QuickMath, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

On a side-note and looking at the rest of the code, it really worth mentioning that binding mechanism is expected to segregate UI from the data, where XAML knows about data source object properties (names and types) but not about it's internal implementation, while data source object can have no knowledge about XAML at all. So

1. there should be no calls from data object to `FrameworkElement`s like `MathBox.Text`
2. it's considered a good design to have data object class completely separate from the page or control class.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works! I was previously using `OnPropertyChanged(toName(Boundnumber));` which didn't get me anywhere. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized your `PropertyChanged` event anywhere, so it will never be called. Declare and initialize it like so:

`public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I can't get this to work either. It seems like the `PropertyChanged` event works but I'm thinking the `QuickMath` property isn't getting initialized until it is edited in the UI but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

A TextBox bound to the calculated property `QuickMath` should receive `PropertyChanged` event from it in order to update the text in the field.
Despite your `OrderScreen` implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, it will not raise the event when `QuickMath` is changed because its setter (where the raising of the event is located) is never called. You can fix it, for example, by calling the QuickMath setter from the independent properties setters as suggested in other answers or delegate that work to [DependenciesTracking](https://github.com/ademchenko/DependenciesTracker) lib:

```
public class OrderScreen : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private readonly IDependenciesMap<OrderScreen> _dependenciesMap =
            new DependenciesMap<OrderScreen>()
                .AddDependency(i => i.QuickMath, i => i.BoundNumber + i.BoundNumber2, i => i.BoundNumber, i => i.BoundNumber2);

        public OrderScreen() => _dependenciesMap.StartTracking(this);

        private int _boundNumber2;
        private int _boundNumber;
        private int _quickMath;

        public int QuickMath
        {
            get => _quickMath;
            private set
            {

                if (value != _quickMath)
                {
                    _quickMath = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();

                }
            }
        }

        public int BoundNumber
        {
            get => _boundNumber;
            set
            {
                if (_boundNumber != value)
                {
                    _boundNumber = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public int BoundNumber2
        {
            get => _boundNumber2;
            set
            {
                if (_boundNumber2 != value)
                {
                    _boundNumber2 = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public class Tests_SO_56623403
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test_SO_56623403()
        {
            var sut = new OrderScreen();

            var raisedEventsCount = 0;
            sut.PropertyChanged += (_, args) =>
            {
                if (args.PropertyName == nameof(OrderScreen.QuickMath))
                    ++raisedEventsCount;
            };
            Assert.Multiple(() =>
            {
                Assert.That(sut.QuickMath, Is.EqualTo(0));
                Assert.That(raisedEventsCount, Is.EqualTo(0));
            });

            sut.BoundNumber = 12;
            Assert.Multiple(() =>
            {
                Assert.That(sut.QuickMath, Is.EqualTo(12));
                Assert.That(raisedEventsCount, Is.EqualTo(1));
            });

            sut.BoundNumber2 = 40;
            Assert.Multiple(() =>
            {
                Assert.That(sut.QuickMath, Is.EqualTo(52));
                Assert.That(raisedEventsCount, Is.EqualTo(2));
            });
        }
    }
```